# Flash -> JavaScript -> Java 7 update 45

Tags: java, flash, applet

I am struggling to get a web application that is 90% flash, but also has two applets to work correctly with Java 7 Update 45. The original development targeted Java 6 Update 21.Originally the applets were deployed as unsigned jars in the container.

In this application essentially Flash uses ExternalInterface.call into JavaScript which is invoking LiveConnect into the applets which are then using JNI to invoke dlls it has loaded, and then invoke JavaScript to invoke notifications of the applets status.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Update Manifest files to specify Codebase, Caller-Allowable-Codebase, Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase
2. Obtained an Root CA certificate for jar signing, and signed the updated jars.
3. Installed the Root CA public certificate into Windows certificate manager, and in the Java Keystores.

After making all of these changes the application runs correctly under 2 scenarios.

1. If I disable the next generation JavaPlugin
2. Enable the next generation JavaPlugin and follow the instructions to create a [Deployment Rule Set](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/what_to_do_if_your)

If I attempt to run the application using the next generation JavaPlugin without the DeploymentRuleSet.jar, then the web application locks up.

Can someone please explain why the applet will not function correctly using the next generation JavaPlugin without a Deployment Rule Set?

Manifest attributes:

```
    <attribute name="Codebase" value="https://gsgs:8443/GSUI"/>
    <attribute name="Caller-Allowable-Codebase" value="https://gsgs:8443/GSUI"/>
    <attribute name="Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase" value="https://gsgs:8443/GSUI"/>
    <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions"/>
```

Deployment Rule Set:

```
    <ruleset version="1.0+">
    <rule>
    <id location="https://gsgs:8443/GSUI"/>
    <action permission="run" version="SECURE"/>
    </rule>
    </ruleset>
```

Comment: It turns out that I have Oracle Support so I have taken the question directly to them. I will post any replies as an answer to at least help someone else who encounters the same issue

Comment: *"..I will post any replies.."*  +1